# How many tags is too many for Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tags, containers, google-tag-manager

I want to set up a number of tags within GTM (at the most 25) and noticed in the support section Google states too many can affect the size of the container as well as how much data the browser has to download. As a general rule of thumb is anyone able to tell me how many is too many?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really a question about GTM so much as content you put on your page in general. And in general, the more stuff you have on your page, the longer the page will take to load, and the longer things take to load, the longer the visitor has to wait for your site to be fully displayed and working.

So basically "too many" can loosely be equated with overall page load being "too long". You could have 100 tags that on average take a *total* of half a second to load (e.g. perhaps most of your tags just (potentially) execute 1 line of code like setting a variable), or you could have 1 tag that takes a minute+ to load (e.g. perhaps some code block for some 3rd party script hosted on a bad server that takes forever to respond and maybe also loads lots of other scripts and images and stuff).

So how long is "too long"? There's no "general rule of thumb" here, because it's highly subjective and based on what's in those tags, what your site is (the "theme"/purpose) and who your target audience is.

In fact, I'd say if we're going for "general rule of thumb" instead of "evaluate my specific circumstance", the only truly accurate answer here is to *always* be of the opinion that your site is taking too long to load, so that you always strive to make it load faster, or failing that, make it load in such a way that the visitor doesn't notice or have to wait before interacting with your site.

In any case, I guess the tl;dr of this is GTM is basically telling you it's not some magic box that gets delivered in the same amount of time regardless of what you put into it because that's not how the internet works.

Comment: In hindsight more of a how long is a piece of string question... Awesome response, thanks for the insight.